# How to run two instances of one class asynchronously

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq

I'm working with rabbitMQ and would like to run two instances of consumer asynchronously to increase the speed of receiving messages. I implements Runnable in the consumer class. and do the following thing:

```
public class ConsumerRun {
    public ConsumerRun(){

        Runnable consumerOne = new App();
        Runnable consumerTwo = new App();

        Thread threadOne = new Thread(consumerOne);
        Thread threadTwo = new Thread(consumerTwo);

        threadOne.start();
        threadTwo.start();
    }
}
```

call this class from main class and see that only one thread is working.

When I create a new class the same with my consumer class and run it as a new thread I receive messages two times faster.

Comment: is there enough work for a second thread to run? Is there a thread-safe task/message queue from which to get work for those threads?

Comment: I think it's enough work for the second thread because messages are genereating continuously. and what about thread-safe message queue. I'm not shure about this. how to check/to make it so

Comment: @Nikitin Mikhail You need to form a question with this post.

Comment: how do you "see that only one thread is working"?